# Populate select with initial data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to populate in my template a `<select>` element with data from a form field like this:

**forms.py**

```
class CreatePlayerForm(forms.Form):
    size = forms.CharField()
```

**views.py**

```
class CreatePlayer(FormView):
    ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        boots = Boots.objects.filter(...).values_list('size', flat=True) # return a list

    form.initial['boots'] = boots
```

**template**

```
<select id="leftValues4" size="5" multiple>
    {% for boot in form.boots %}
        <option>{{ boot }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

With the above code I don't get any results.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I can't see how you're intending this to work. You have defined size as a CharField, but then attempt to output a select field manually in the template. Why? Why not use a proper field with choices in the form definition, and allow the form to display it automatically?

Comment: @DanielRoseman This was just a basic example of what I'm trying to do. What I need is populate the select with the list obtained in the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not approaching this in the right way at all.

`initial` is specifically for pre-setting the *chosen* value. You are trying to populate the *list* of values. For that, you will need to use an actual field that supports such a list; and that is a ChoiceField, not a CharField.

Secondly, choices need to have an ID value as well as a display value; so you need a list/tuple of 2-tuples.

form:

```
class CreatePlayerForm(forms.Form):
    size = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sizes = kwargs.pop('sizes')
        super(CreatePlayerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sizes'].choices = sizes
```

view:

```
class CreatePlayer(FormView):
    ...
    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super(CreatePlayer, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        boots = Boots.objects.filter(...).values_list('id', 'size')
        form_kwargs['sizes'] = boots
        return form_kwargs
```

template:

```
{{ form.boots }}
```

Comment: What is the function of `sizes = kwargs.pop('sizes')`